# How to set focus on element

Tags: focus

I am a noob...
I have a form with an input box (textfield) and submit button. what I am trying to do is when the submit button is pressed, I would like for the focus to go back to the text field for the next input.

I have tried the following codes - none worked:

- document.getElementByID("textfield").focus();
- onsubmit
- onblur

and a function statement (in the code below)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>title</title>

    </head>
    <body>



        <form method="POST" action="mon_am.php">
        <input type="text" name="mon_am">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" onblur="focusMethod()"> 

    </form>
    <script> 
            focusMethod = function getFocus() 
            {           
            $("input[name='mon_am']").focus();
            } 
     </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit a form, the page reloads.  Consider adding focus to the form when the page loads (Which gives the advantage of being ready for the user the first time they visit the page).  Change your field to include an id:

```
<input type="text" name="mon_am" id="mon_am">
```

And in your script tag, add:

```
window.onload = function() {
 document.getElementById("mon_am").focus();
};
```

Comment: Or using the HTML attribute "autofocus" for the "input" HTML tag?